# How can I determine if an object is of type "text" or "checkbox"?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("input[id^='Order_'], input[id^='Default_']").change(function (e) {
   var type = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[0];
   updateField('Menu', $(this), type);
});
```

In the updateField function is there a way that I can determine if the obj passed is of a type "text" or "checkbox"?

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
    var val = obj.val();
    var val = obj.is(":checked")
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with the current code? It seems you are doing it in right way.

Answer (score 3):

You can inspect the field's 'type' attribute:

```
obj.attr('type');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var value;
if (obj.attr('type') === 'text') {
    value = obj.val();
} else if (obj.attr('type') === 'checkbox') {
    value = !!obj.attr('checked');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:text` and `:checkbox` type selectors:

```
obj.is(":checkbox") // returns true if element is of type checkbox
obj.is(":text") // returns true if element is of type text
```

[See here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for all jQuery selectors.

**Update following comment**

Assuming `obj` will always be of type `text` or `checkbox`:

```
var val = obj.is(":text") ? obj.val() : obj.is(":checked");
```

Comment: What I want to do is to store the value of "true" / "false" in variable val if it is a checkbox or the actual value if it is text. Is there an easy way I can do this based on using maybe an if or something like that?

Comment: Better than that `var val = obj.is(":checked") ? true : obj.val();` :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure Not really, if `val` is a checkbox that is not checked, val will be undefined, not false.

Comment: @Jessica Here's some useful info to understand what the `(condition) ? arg : arg` syntax means incase you haven't encountered it before: [Ternary operators](http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.attr()` to get the type attribute and use an `if statement` to determine which type it is.

e.g.

```
var type = obj.attr('type');

if (type == "checkbox") {

// It's a checkbox

} else if (type == "text") {

//It's text

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var typeAttr = obj.attr("type");
```

Answer (score 2):

What I often do is:

```
var nodeType...
nodeType = $(this).attr("type") || $(this).nodeName.toLowerCase();
```

so it works for every input type.

For a textbox it will contain:

```
textarea
```

and for a checkbox it will contain

```
checkbox
```

etc.
A complete example:

```
function inputType = function( $input ){
    if( !$input.length ) {
     return false;
    }
    return $input.attr("type") || $input.nodeName.toLowerCase();
}

inputType( $("input[type=text]") ) //returns text
inputType( $("textarea") ) //returns textarea
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function updateField(entity, obj, type) {
var val = obj.val();
var whatAmI = obj.attr('type');  // <====
if (whatAmI == 'text')
{
}
else
{
}
var val = obj.is(":checked")
```

Comment: Thanks, Can I make my code put something into the variable val depending if it is a checkbox or text? I was thinking to use and if statement but I am not sure how to declare val.

Comment: Check answer given by rick or mine. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 var val = obj.attr("type") == 'text' 
            ? obj.val() //Value of text box
            : obj.attr("type") == 'checkbox'; //if it's a check box or not
```